How to Efficiently Manage General and Personal Data Storage in a React Native App?
I'm developing a React Native application that will handle both general data (like static content) and personal data (such as user progress and personal information). I'm trying to find the most efficient and scalable approach to manage and store these types of data.
Thank you in advance!
I’m considering the following approach:
Using a relational database (e.g., MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite) or NoSQL database (e.g., MongoDB) for storing general data.
Separately managing personal data, including implementing user authentication with options like Firebase Authentication or Auth0.
Employing REST API or GraphQL for communication between the frontend and backend, using Axios or Fetch API.
Exploring caching, lazy loading, and data compression to optimize app performance and manage size.
I'm looking for feedback on this approach and any alternative methods or best practices that could improve data management in a React Native app.
